# How to test directive which template have ng-include inside the ng-repeat

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I write a directive. In the template i have used ng-include inside the ng-repeat:

```
 <div ng-repeat="page in wStepPages" id="step{{$index}}"  data-ng-show="getCurrentStep() == $index" ng-include="page.page" class="slide-frame">
</div>
```

For example if my page.page = step1.html:

```
<div>
  <input id="name" ng-model="isolate.name">
</div>
```

And in my testSpec:

```
describe("test_wizard",function () {
var scope,doc,elem,compiled,html;


beforeEach(module('App.wizard','app/partials/step1.html','app/partials/step2.html','app/partials/step3.html','app/partials/step4.html'));
beforeEach(function(){
    html = '<ov-wizard title="OV_WIZARD" step-pages="stepPages" confirm-bt="confirmbt" data="wizardData"></ov-wizard>';
    inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        elem = angular.element(html);
        compiled = $compile(elem);
        compiled(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    })
});

it("do some thing",function(){

expect(elem.find("#name").length).toEqual(1);
});

})
```

But it return is 0 item.
Any help me!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element):

> find() - Limited to lookups by tag name